# Displaying images from data table in a loop one at a time

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to write code that displays images from a datatable one at a time with a delay between each display in a continuous loop.
The issue I am having is only the first image is displaying, can anyone see where I have gone wrong or am I approaching this the wrong way?

PHP

```
<?php while($row_fb = mysqli_fetch_array($fb)){ 
   $url = $ImagePath.''.$row_fb['SignageImageName']; ?>
   <div id="banner-container">
     <a><img src="/<?php echo $url;?>"/></a>
   </div>
<?php
}?>
```

CSS

```
#banner-container a {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
#banner-container {
  position: relative;
}
```

JQUERY

```
(function() {
  var a = $('#banner-container').children();
  var index = 0;
  run()

  function run() {
    a.filter('.active').fadeOut(500).removeClass('active');
    a.eq(index).fadeIn(500).addClass('active');
    index = (index + 1) % a.length; // Wraps around if it hits the end
    setTimeout(run, 5000);
  }
})();
```

Comment: use `sleep()` function inside loop for delay in every iteration of loop.

Comment: @ Faizan Ali  Hi and thanks for the reply. If I use sleep(2000) in side the loop it still only displays the first image of three images.

Comment: Where is the class `'active'` defined?

Comment: All your div's have `id="banner-container"`. id's have to be unique. So it's always targetting the first one.

Comment: Hi, you mean like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jqLfg9ky/) ?

Comment: @ Swati Hi, that's what I was trying to do. Many thanks for your reply.